# Cassandra - order by composite key and time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE datapoints (
  id UUID,
  collection_id UUID,
  time TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id), collection_id, time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (collection_id ASC,time ASC);
```

I would like that the data points are ordered by a collection id and time, however, it seems to be including the id in the ordering.

Here is an output example:

```
 id                                   | collection_id                        | time
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------
 08fc3461-4c1c-40ef-a9ba-aeedd454c0b4 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:27:00+0100
 93c32778-52fc-4568-872f-3697799f60a7 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:14:00+0100
 16d7c8df-f5a4-4b59-8f20-e6bd49e576c7 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:04:00+0100
 acbd2a04-64e5-419b-8140-3256f984e3c7 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:13:00+0100
 faadfee0-8968-4f69-885a-9f2b37e444b3 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:28:00+0100
 9d306504-ec00-4138-a9c6-531b3552ad8e | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:49:00+0100
 bedb143f-22a4-4ed7-90e5-ba0c0cecee57 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:20:00+0100
 b8a4eee5-64b3-418a-9cea-84e02a5172c7 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:21:00+0100
 f17beb58-905b-4253-a472-b8726d86bc04 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:05:00+0100
 83fbba8e-b06a-4763-b66b-47ffad907972 | 32c9fdd9-de41-4bb0-9ea6-7a30371df43e | 2013-02-01 00:19:00+0100
```

As you can see it is not ordered by time. How can I do it so the id is ignored (I need an id as I might need to update a record) for the ordering and *only* order the records by a collection id and time. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I could drop the id as a primary key and just create an index for it - this would solve the problem. It would be nice to keep the id as a primary key though...

Comment: The clustering column determine the data’s on-disk sort order only within a partition key.
source: http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/

Comment: @ZainMalik Great link. Thank you!